# Indoor lucky bamboo

Tags: indoors, lucky-bamboo

I was given a small stalk and now it is in gravel in a Ball jelly canning jar.

How do I care for it, when do I transplant, do I put it in soil or gravel, and how to properly water it? Currently it is growing really good I dont want to hurt it.

Answer (score 2):

Lucky Bamboos are Dracaena Sanderiana plants you can check what cares does it need on sites like [this one](http://www.plantsrescue.com/dracaena-sanderiana/)

Dracaenas Sanderiana grows in water, there are other kinds of Dracaenas that grow in soil. Usually they grow really well in Ball Jelly because they provide moisture, air and nutrients, so you can keep it in Ball jelly and change the jelly from time to time.

> **Proper Care:** Dracaena sanderiana requires a constant clean water
>   source and well lit area. It must maintain moisture and it is
>   important to keep it out of direct sunlight. The Dracaena sanderiana
>   does not require pruning, but fertilizing it occasionally with the
>   Lucky Bamboo liquid fertilizer may help it healthy. Dracaena
>   sanderiana is a tender dracaena, this plant requires protection from
>   excessive sun and wind; it prefers areas of rich, well-watered,
>   well-drained soil; nor a dryland or beach plant.
>
> **Water**: Water level should be at least 5cm (2 in). Make sure the roots
>   are covered with water; add water to keep the water level constant.
>   Every couple of weeks change the water completely. Refill the
>   container with clean water. Dracaena sanderiana is sensitive to the
>   salts and chemicals in tap water; use distilled water or rainwater if
>   possible. If you must use tap water let it set in an open container
>   over night; this will let the chlorine evaporate. However, there is no
>   way to remove the fluoride from the tap water. Fluoride can cause leaf
>   tips to turn brown. Low humidity can cause leaf tips to turn brown as
>   well. Mist the leaves of the Dracaena sanderiana every couple of days
>   if lack of humidity is a problem.
>
> Fertilize your Dracaena sanderiana every couple of months (you can go
>   longer). A diluted (tenth of the normal strength) water-soluble
>   houseplant fertilizer. The best time to fertilize is when you change
>   the water. Lucky Bamboo liquid fertilizer is a handy fertilizer to
>   use.